# How to speed up an animation in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I've already tried to decrease the `interval` argument which, by the way, only plotted to values ​​greater than 1. When I tried `interval=0.05`, for example, the pycharm generated an empty plot. I also wanted to know how to save these animations, probably, in gif format. The code currently looks like this:

```
fig= plt.figure()
    plt.xlabel("x/M")
    plt.ylabel("y/M")
    circle = Circle((0, 0), 3 * math.sqrt(3), color='dimgrey')
    plt.gca().add_patch(circle)
    plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
    ax = plt.axes()
    ax.set_facecolor("black")
    plt.axis([-1 / u1 - 5, 1 / u1 + 5, -1 / u1 - 5, 1 / u1 + 5])
    graph, = plt.plot([],[],'o', color="gold", markersize=2)
    def animate(i):
        graph.set_data(x[:i+1],y[:i+1])
        return graph
    ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, repeat=False, interval=1)
    ani.save('orbita.gif', writer='imagemagick', fps=30)
```

Comment: `FuncAnimation` needs a parameter `frames` telling it how many separate images you want, e.g. `frames=len(x)`.  Also, the return statement of `animate` needs a trailing comma as in `return graph,`.

Comment: I tried using ```frames = len (x)``` but it didn't change the speed of the gif. Is it possible to use any  ```interval```  less than 1? Or, what else can I do to make the intervals shorter?

Comment: The interval is for the speed on screen when generating the animation.  To change the speed of the gif, you need the `fps` parameter of ´an.´

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`interval`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html) is for the speed on screen when generating the animation. It is measured in milliseconds, and should be an integer. Setting `interval=1` is already faster than most computers can show the frames.

To change the speed of the `.gif`, you need the `fps` parameter of ´ani.save´, for example `anim.save('test.gif', writer='imagemagick', fps=60)` would be 60 frames per second, so 60 images in 1 second. (100 fps is the maximum that the `.gif` format allows, but most applications can't show images that fast, nor do most screens update that fast. Therefore, 30 fps is usually a good choice.)

If your data is very long, you might want to use less frames, and add more points in one `animate()` step. Here is an example that adds 20 points at each step.

```py
graph, = plt.plot([],[],'o', color="gold", markersize=2)

def animate(i):
    graph.set_data(x[:i*20],y[:i*20])
    return graph,  # the comma is needed here

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, repeat=False, interval=1, frames=len(x)//20)
ani.save('orbita.gif', writer='imagemagick', fps=30)
```

Also make sure that your `x` and `y` arrays correctly contain the points of the curve you want to show. And that these points lie within the coordinates set by `plt.axis([-1 / u1 - 5, 1 / u1 + 5, -1 / u1 - 5, 1 / u1 + 5])`. As a check, you might want to draw just the curve, without animation.

Comment: _"Setting `interval=1` is already faster than most computers can show the frames."_ Possibly even more important, it's way faster than ordinary computer displays are able to receive...